# How to handle TokenMistmatchException in axios

Tags: laravel, exception, vuejs2, axios

A token mistmatch occurs when the page stays for so long till session variable expires...

I can handle this exception in  handler.php under exceptions in normal laravel blade files but having problems handling this error with axios post request in vue.js.

I have tried using

try..catch (TokenMistsmatchException $e)

but I still cant get a json reaponse in my axios response callback.

I am trying to find solutions in these ways

1. Either I find a way to refresh the token when expired before the exception gets triggered
2. To get a response to my axios callback so I reload the page from within my vue template.

Your helps will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app/Exceptions/Handler.php file

Add a handler for TokenMismatchException in the render method

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
if ($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException) {
    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json([
            'error' => 'Token mismatch'
        ], $exception->getStatusCode());
    };
}

return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

> After this you can catch errors in axios like

```
axios.post(pathname", { body:body })
     .catch(error => {
         handle error / Display error message
     })
     .then(({ data }) => {
         If successfully request performed
     });
```

Comment: You just solved my problem, thank you! Anyways, I was not able to get the error in the catch callback but in the main response, no problem whatsoever as the job is done, thanks.

Comment: You just solved my problem, thank you! Anyways, I was not able to get the error in the catch callback but in the main response, no problem whatsoever as the job is done, thanks.

Comment: happy to help :)